# JSON array unset

Tags: php, json, database

First of all, I really don't know if that kind of topic exist. But I searched a lot and now I am here.

My question about parsing. For example I would like to unset some items.

```
$now = array();
$now[0]['name'] = "Hello1";
$now[0]['si'] = "BumBum1";
$now[1]['name'] = "Hello2";
$now[1]['si'] = "BumBum2";
$now[2]['name'] = "Hello3";
$now[2]['si'] = "BumBum3";
$now[3]['name'] = "Hello4";
$now[3]['si'] = "BumBum4";

echo json_encode($now)."<br>";

unset($now[0]);

echo json_encode($now);
```

And the output:

```
[{"name":"Hello1","si":"BumBum1"},{"name":"Hello2","si":"BumBum2"},{"name":"Hello3","si":"BumBum3"},{"name":"Hello4","si":"BumBum4"}]

{"1":{"name":"Hello2","si":"BumBum2"},"2":{"name":"Hello3","si":"BumBum3"},"3":{"name":"Hello4","si":"BumBum4"}}
```

And my the JSON file turns to messy code. Appears numbers and etc.
Any ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Tried with objects. Same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "reindex" the array (use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function).

```
//unset..
unset($now[0]);

//reindex
$now = array_values($now);

//display as before
echo json_encode($now);
```

Comment: I just forgot that.. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answer helped you: upvote, if answer is correct mark it as such.